# VSCode Python + OpenCV Path Not Working [Windows]

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, opencv

I am drawing boxes around faces with OpenCV in VSCode using python.

I coded the entire thing on my MacBook where it worked fine, and when i moved it to my windows computer, the Haar Cascade path wasn't being found. I'm relatively new to python and don't know what the issue is, here is the path i have in the python script:

```
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("d:\lib\site-packages\cv2\data\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('d:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cv2\data\haarcascade_eye.xml')
```

I've tried different paths, including a raw string format and only including the name, but nothing seems to work. It works fine on my macbook, but not on my windows machine. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: replace every ```\``` in the path with ```\\```

Comment: Use `/` and [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html); Windows paths are just a disaster

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the same python code as before, and that the path is correct? The path should NOT be the same as before of course, it should point to where the file really is on your windows computer. Are you running the code in the same directory as the xml file? How are you running the code? A little more context is needed to determine exactly what the issue is, I would take a look at this:

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d28/tutorial_cascade_classifier.html

(^Forgive me if that's all old news, you said you were a python beginner which is why I included that)

This can't be an issue with VS Code or your programming environment, because in the case of Python, you can run it directly in the terminal. Open a command window or powershell, `cd` into the directory of the python file and run `python myprogram.py`. If that's not working, test again with something very basic, like

```python
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("image.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

where `image.jpg` is stored in the same directory as `myprogram.py`. If you're able to see a window pop up with an image, then your python configuration is fine and it's an issue with the program itself/how you're using CascadeClassifier, or how the path to the file is configured.